# Automating excel report

Tags: scripting, spreadsheet

Could you please help me for the below concerns.

1. I'll be executing one script which gives some output
2. Have to arrange them in a table format in excel
3. Attach the excel and send it through mail

Anyone please suggest idea for automating the above steps. I can do 1st and 3rd step but i've no idea regarding the second step :(

Comment: @Gilles.. Can you pls help on this topic, pls guide me since i'm a newbie http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45322/could-not-find-filesystem-dev-root

Answer (score 7):

I take it you've got some values and you want to create a file that Excel can read.  The easiest-to-create [file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#File_formats) Excel understands probably is [CSV, comma-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), i.e. a plain text file like this example (from Wikipedia):

```
Year,Make,Model,Description,Price
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""","",5000.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00
```

Now, there are several ways to create CSV files.  In very simple cases, [`sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CSV+%5Bsed%5D&submit=search) or [`awk`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CSV+%5Bawk%5D&submit=search) might do; however, there're many tools/libraries designed for this task, [the answers here (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1063125/993018) mention a few.  (The [CRUSH (Custom Reporting Utilities for SHell) tools](http://code.google.com/p/crush-tools/) mentioned there might be interesting for step 1., too.)

Comment: But in csv files we cannot create tables right !! So can you suggest any alternative in which i can create table and fill values automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure about this.  Just try it, save some Excel-work as CSV and examine it... If you want to create something too fancy, there might be better methods, e.g. [using Python](http://www.python-excel.org/) or something like [DataNitro (formerly called IronSpread)](https://datanitro.com/product.html).